# Are momentum and (mini-) batch training compatible?

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I had a backpropagation model which worked perfectly fine, however I wanted to implemented batch training.

Code before batch training (in backpropagation function), pseudocode:

```
forevery(connection in this.connections.in){
  // Adjust weight
  var deltaWeight = rate * gradient + momentum * connection.previousDeltaWeight;
  connection.weight += deltaWeight;
  connection.previousDeltaWeight = deltaWeight;
}

// Adjust bias
var deltaBias = rate * this.error.responsibility + momentum * this.previousDeltaBias;
this.bias += deltaBias;

this.previousDeltabias = deltaBias;
```

And the new code is:

```
forevery(connection in this.connections.in){
  // Adjust weight
  var deltaWeight = rate * gradient * this.mask + momentum * connection.previousDeltaWeight;
  connection.totalDeltaWeight += deltaWeight;
  if(update){
    connection.weight += connection.totalDeltaWeight;
    connection.previousDeltaWeight = connection.totalDeltaWeight;
    connection.totalDeltaWeight = 0;
  }
}

// Adjust bias
var deltaBias = rate * this.error.responsibility + momentum * this.previousDeltaBias;
this.totalDeltaBias += deltaBias;
if(update){
  this.bias += this.totalDeltaBias;
  this.previousDeltaBias = this.totalDeltaBias;
  this.totalDeltaBias = 0;
}
```

So if the batch size is 4, the backpropagation gets called 3x with `update=false` and the 4th time with `update=true`. The batch training works fine, but when I turn on momentum `(=0.9)` all the values start overflowing. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I was accumulating the momentum wrong. I included it `batch_size` times which was wrong, so it is now only included once.

```
forevery(connection in this.connections.in){
  // Adjust weight
  var deltaWeight = rate * gradient * this.mask;
  connection.totalDeltaWeight += deltaWeight;
  if(update){
    connection.totalDeltaWeight += momentum * connection.previousDeltaWeight;
    connection.weight += connection.totalDeltaWeight;
    connection.previousDeltaWeight = connection.totalDeltaWeight;
    connection.totalDeltaWeight = 0;
  }
}

// note: MINI_BATCH SHALL BE OPTIMIZED SOON

// Adjust bias
var deltaBias = rate * this.error.responsibility;
this.totalDeltaBias += deltaBias;
if(update){
  this.totalDeltaBias += momentum * this.previousDeltaBias;
  this.bias += this.totalDeltaBias;
  this.previousDeltaBias = this.totalDeltaBias;
  this.totalDeltaBias = 0;
}
```